# Google glass clear cache

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I was trying to resize an image to fit into a timeline template. (if it matters, I'm using the html attribute of the timeline) However, it was not rendering it properly. I got frustrated. Then I figured out that glass is using the same image. I just changed the name of the image and the url and it worked. Is there a way to clear the cache ? There might be a scenario where you change images on the server side and have the same timeline item (say a pinned item) access them at some other time interval. Thoughts ?

**UPDATE**

Request submitted in issue tracker

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=30&thanks=30&ts=1367387959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in feature that triggers the timeline to clear it's cache, but it does respect the cache headers that you set. During development, use [cache control headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) to prevent the image from being cached.

If this isn't possible, you can work around this by adding a random GET parameter to the end of the image URL when you insert the card into your user's timeline.

All that being said, this seems like a useful development feature. You may want to request it in the [API issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Answer (score -2):

put the same answer on your g+ but here it goes:

If you can enable adb, try using "adb reboot recovery" and see if you can get the option to pop up there.

Usually to get a menu up in recovery you have to press power and the up volume key (which i would assume would be the only other key on glass in this case) at the same time. then the volume key(s) scroll through options and the power button selects one.

Let me know if it works out.﻿